# Как удалить денвер с компа?

Tags: denwer

До того как загрузил денвер localhost работал а потом загрузил и не понравилось и удалил потом гугл начал писать Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
И сейчас опять загрузил денвер не работает и не могу полностью удалить.

Answer (score 1):

1. Остановить Денвер
2. Если виртуальный диск создаётся по умолчанию, в Start -> Run нужно выполнить следующую команду (если необходимо, заменить Z на Вашу букву виртуального диска): 
   subst Z: /D
3. Удалить папку инсталляции Денвера (по умолчанию C:\WebServers)
4. Удалить, если необходимо, ярлык из Автозагрузки
5. Удалить ярлыки Запуска/Останова Комплекса

Comment: Я удалил но уменя опять же не работает и icon это джендльмеснкий набор

Comment: @Nigga, почисти реестр после удаления денвера

Comment: А как это делать?

Comment: например, с помощью CCleaner или подобной программы